# How to publish to friends wall using fbml?

Tags: facebook

How to publish some result from my app to someones wall by selecting the friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [Stream.publish](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish) method. In short the `target_id` parameter is what you're looking for.

There's a pretty good example in the wiki link above.